# Solving PDE with Matlab

Tags: matlab, pde

```
`sol = pdepe(m,@ParticleDiffusionpde,@ParticleDiffusionic,@ParticleDiffusionbc,x,t);
% Extract the first solution component as u.
u = sol(:,:,:); 

function [c,f,s] = ParticleDiffusionpde(x,t,u,DuDx)
global Ds 
c = 1/Ds;
f = DuDx;
s = 0;

function u0 = ParticleDiffusionic(x)
global qo
u0 = qo;

function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = ParticleDiffusionbc(xl,ul,xr,ur,t,x)

global Ds K n
global Amo Gc kf rhop
global uavg
global dr R nr

sum = 0;
for i = 1:1:nr-1
r1 = (i-1)*dr; % radius at i
r2 = i * dr; % radius at i+1
r1 = double(r1); % convert to double precision
r2 = double(r2);
sum = sum + (dr / 2 * (r1*ul+ r2*ur));
end;
uavg = 3/R^3 * sum;

ql = 1;
pl = 0;

qr = 1;
pr = -((kf/(Ds.*rhop)).*(Amo - Gc.*uavg - ((double(ur/K)).^2).^(n/2) ));`


dq(r,t)/dt = Ds( d2q(r,t)/dr2 + (2/r)*dq(r,t)/dr )

q(r, t=0) = 0

dq(r=0, t)/dr = 0

dq(r=dp/2, t)/dr = (kf/Ds*rhop) [C(t) - Cp(at r = dp/2)]

q = solid phase concentration of trace compound in a particle with radius dp/2

C = bulk liquid concentration of trace compound

Cp = trace compound concentration at particle surface
```

I want to solve the above pde with initial and boundary conditions given. Tried Matlab's pdepe, but does not work satisfactorily. Maybe the boundary conditions is creating problem for me. I also used this isotherm equation for equilibrium: `q = K*Cp^(1/n)`. This is convection-diffusion equation but i could not find any write ups that addresses solving this type of equation properly.

Comment: What is `C(t)` and `Cp(r)`?  Known, specified functions or are non-linearly related to `q` or something else?

Comment: thank you for your response. Cp = trace compound concentration at particle surface i.e at dp/2. it's time dependent not r, i think. C = concentration of trace compound at bulk liquid. Cp is related with q i.e. q = K*Cp^(1/n) and also time dependent. there is another equation available to calculate C which is : C(t) = Co (at t =0) - (mp/Vp)*qavg(t).  So C and Cp are related to q. This a problem of trace compound adsorption by Granular carbon particle.

Comment: Okay.  It seems like `pdepe` is the correct utility to use in this situation.  Could you post the code you used that is generating the unsatisfactory output?  Without an [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can't proceed much farther.

Comment: i have an excel file for data input which i can not link so I provided the outline of the basic code. I was thinking if I can use the finite difference method using crank-nicholson and then solve it in matlab rather than pdepe?

Comment: Anyone plz help me/ guide me!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  It took a bit to figure out how to calculate the average appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the current implementation.

### Incorrect Source Term

The PDE you are attempting to solve has the form

[image: PDE from OP]

which has the equivalent form

[image: Alternate form of the PDE]

where the last term arises due to the factor of 2 in the original PDE.
The last term needs to be incorporated into `pdepe` via a source term.

### Calculation of `q` average

The current implementation attempts to calculate the average value of `q` using the left and right values of `q` passed to the boundary condition function.
This is incorrect.
The average value of `q` needs to be calculated from a vector of up-to-date values of the quantity.

However, we have the complication that the only function to receive all mesh values is `ParticleDiffusionpde`; however, the mesh values passed to that function are not guaranteed to be from the mesh we provided.

Solution: use events (as described in the [`pdepe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html) documentation).
This is a hack since the event function is meant to detect zero-crossings, but it has the advantage that the function is given all values of `q` on the mesh we provide.

So, the working example below (you'll notice I set all of the parameters to `1` since I didn't know better) uses the `events` function to update a variable `qStore` that can be accessed by the boundary condition function ([see here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html#f4-73993) for an explanation), and the boundary condition function performs a vectorized trapezoidal integration for the average calculation.

### Working Example

```
function [] = ParticleDiffusion()

    %   Parameters
    Ds   = 1;
    q0   = 0;
    K    = 1;
    n    = 1;
    Amo  = 1;
    Gc   = 1;
    kf   = 1;
    rhop = 1;

    %   Space
    rMesh = linspace(0,1,10);
    rMesh = rMesh(:) ;
    dr    = rMesh(2) - rMesh(1) ; 

    %   Time
    tSpan = linspace(0,1,10);

    %   Vector to store current u-value
    qStore = zeros(size(rMesh));

    options.Events = @(m,t,x,y) events(m,t,x,y);

    %   Solve
    [sol,~,~,~,~] = pdepe(1,@ParticleDiffusionpde,@ParticleDiffusionic,@ParticleDiffusionbc,rMesh,tSpan,options);



    %   Use the events function to update qStore
    function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(m,~,~,y)
        qStore     = y; % Value of q on rMesh
        value      = m; % Since m is constant, it will never be zero (no event detection)
        isterminal = 0; % Continue integration
        direction  = 0; % Detect all zero crossings (not important)
    end


    function [c,f,s] = ParticleDiffusionpde(r,~,~,DqDr)

        %   Define the capacity, flux, and source
        c = 1/Ds;
        f = DqDr;
        s = DqDr./r;

    end

    function u0 = ParticleDiffusionic(~)
        u0 = q0;
    end

    function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = ParticleDiffusionbc(~,~,R,ur,~)

        %   Calculate average value of current solution
        qL    = qStore(1:end-1);
        qR    = qStore(2: end );
        total = sum((qL.*rMesh(1:end-1) + qR.*rMesh(2:end))) * dr/2;
        qavg  = 3/R^3 * total;

        %   Left boundary
        pl = 0;
        ql = 1;

        %   Right boundary
        qr = 1;
        pr = -(kf/(Ds.*rhop)).*(Amo - Gc.*qavg - (ur/K).^n);
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you Troy!! but give me some time to figure out what are you talking about and i will get back to you! if you want you can leave ur email address here so that i can contact u!!! and thanks again

Comment: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in pdepe (line 336)
    sole(:,:,i) = ye(:,i:npde:end);                                                                          This is the error when I run your solution. and also i did not understand why value in the events function is equal to m

Comment: `events` exists purely to update `qStore`.  I set `value` equal to `m` because then no events will be detected since `m` is a constant values of `1` (looking at this now, I should have just put `value = 1;`).  The solution to the PDE lies in `sol` only, the event outputs will all be empty.

Comment: ok I got your point. Now I have two more questions/concerns :)                      1.  dq(r,t)/dt = Ds( d2q(r,t)/dr2 + (2/r)*dq(r,t)/dr )     --- this equation has another form too 1/Ds * dq(r,t)/dt = (1/r^2) * d/dr [ r^2 * dq(r,t)/dr ]. In that case m = 2 and no correction of source term is needed.   2. the error when I run your solution is "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch". The Error is in pdepe (line 336) sole(:,:,i) = ye(:,i:npde:end). Is this ODE15s's inherent problem? What can I do to overcome this?

Comment: @NabilaFarah Good point; I forgot about spherical because I don't use it ever.  Concerning the error (as you mentioned last): what is `ye` and why are you assigning it to the solution?  Once `pdepe` finishes, the solution in `sol` (or `sole` for you) shouldn't be changed.